# Find the equation of the sinusoidal wave from the given figure

Tags: solution-verification, wave-equation

**Wave is traveling in positive direction**
[image]

Clearly, the amplitude $A=0.2$ and wavelength $\lambda =5$ and time period $T=\frac 12$

So $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} = \frac{2\pi}{5}$

And $\omega =\frac{2\pi}{T} =4\pi$

So
$$y=0.2 \sin (\omega t -kx \pm \phi)$$
$$y=0.2 \sin (4\pi t-\frac{2\pi x}{5} +\phi)$$

Now I have a problem with the phase of the way. I think it should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$

So $$y=0.2 \cos (4\pi t -\frac{2\pi}{5} x )$$

But the given answer is $y=0.2 \cos (\frac{2\pi x}{5} - 4\pi t)$

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\cos$ is an even function

$$
\cos (-z) = \cos (z) \tag{1}
$$

which means

$$
0.2\cos\left(4\pi t - \frac{2\pi}{5}x \right) = 0.2\cos\left[-\left(-4\pi t + \frac{2\pi}{5}x \right)\right] \stackrel{(1)}{=} 0.2 \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}x - 4\pi t \right)
$$

Comment: Is phase right though?

Comment: @Aditya If you set $t=0$ and $x=5$ in your solution you'll get

$$
y(x=5, t=0) = 0.2\cos(-2\pi) = 0.2\cos(2\pi) = 0.2
$$

that matches with the first figure. So yeah, your choice of phase is correct